# Role Change lag - WSO2 IS 5.11.0 and WSO2 APIM 3.2.0

Tags: jdbc, wso2, wso2-api-manager, scim2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 and WSO2 IS 5.11.0
Both of them use the common shared_db (Postgres DB) using JDBC.
So the users and roles created in WSO2 IS (using carbon portal / scim 2.0 API) will be reflected in the WSO2 APIM also.

When I perform role update using SCIM 2.0 API supported by WSO2 IS (modify the role), we could see the changes are getting reflected in both WSO2 IS carbon portal and the DB immediately, but in WSO2 APIM carbon portal the old role is only seen even when refreshed.
After 3 to 5 minutes only it is getting reflected in WSO2 APIM carbon portal.

Can anyone let me know the issue reason and how it can be resolved?
I need this role update to be reflected immediately in WSO2 APIM carbon portal also.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to user role cache. It stores the user roles in an in-memory cache.

Following are the default configurations for this user role cache. You may change these and try out.

```
[user_store.properties]
UserRolesCacheEnabled = true
UserCoreCacheTimeOut = 5
```

Disabling this cache would not be a good idea since it would affect the performance. The timeout is in minutes.

Moreover, as per the documentation, APIM 3.2.0 and IS 5.11.0 are not compatible with each other. APIM 3.2.0 goes with IS 5.10.0 and APIM 4.0 goes with IS 5.11.0.